# .each(function{} .split and .attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently came across these codes while learning how to program an animated gallery and have no idea what they mean:

```
var items = $('#gallery li'),
        itemsByTags = {};
items.each(function(i){
        var elem = $(this),
        tags = elem.data('tags').split(',');        
//Add data attribute for quicksand
        elem.attr('data-id',i);
```

I know that the `var items = $('#gallery li'),itemsByTags = {};`means that I am grabbing the list ID through jQuery and then setting a variable named `itemsByTags`to an empty string.

After which `items.each` is a loop that is design to run through all the lists. But i have no idea what is `function(i)`? Why is there an `i` inside the function? What is this `i`thing?

Also, what does `$(this)` mean? Does it refer to the `items`?

Lastly, what does the `.attr()` mean with the `i` inside?

Comment: Change question title to better sequence !

Comment: Go through this url to understand how .each in jquery works: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Have you considered the [**.each() | jQuiery API Documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/each/)? If you still have a question after you do, let us know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as a warning, questions like this one aren't very highly regarded on Stack Overflow because they can be answered by visiting a single page about the function you're using, which in this case would be the [documentation for the jQuery .each() function](https://api.jquery.com/each/). Questions like this one are often downvoted and never get an answer, so before posting a question, you should always check the documentation for the code or libraries that you are using to see if your question may already be answered there.

With that out of the way, here are a couple of points that should help answer your questions:

`itemsByTags = {};` sets the variable to an empty *object*, not a string. This variable is not used in the code you provided, though, so it's not very relevant to the question at hand.

`items.each(function(i){` is, as you noted, a function designed to loop through an array of items. `Each` functions normally output two different values, a *key* and a *value*. In this case, however, only one variable is supplied in the function call, and so the function will only receive the first value, which is *key*. The key is the 0-based index of the number of the item you are on. This number will increase by 1 each time you move to the next item in an array. A different way of explaining this would be to say that `array[key]` would return the `value` in `array` at item number `key`.

`$(this)` is jQuery's way of referring to the object currently being retrieved from the array. Because `var items = $('#gallery li')` retrieves a list of all of the *objects* in the page that match the selector `#gallery li`, `$(this)` refers to the actual object in the page whose array element is being retrieved. `$(this)` can be modified and acted on in the same way as if you targeted it using a normal selector like `$('#gallery li').eq(i)`.

You may have determined by now exactly what the last line is doing. `$(this).attr('data-id',i);` finds the current array item's element in the page and sets its `data-id` attribute to its 0-based index relative to its siblings. If you iterate through the array in this way, the 6th (just for example) `$('#gallery li')` element's `data-id` attribute would be changed to `5`.

Hope this is helpful!